# "Unanswered" questions with answers in comments

Tags: discussion

I was browsing through the unanswered perl questions, and came across several in a short time where either the asker or another user answered the question in a comment rather than an answer. I posted a comment suggesting a proper end of the question, but the number of these such questions I encountered made me consider alternate methods. Is there currently a policy or accepted procedure for a question (perhaps even 1+ years old) that has a solution, but is not answered in the SO sense?

I don't want to answer the question myself, since it's not my answer, but having the question linger in the unanswered section seems wrong too.

Comment: answer it yourself, with a link to the profile of the commenter for attribution. If you don't want to get rep from it, make it a community wiki :)

Comment: Thanks --- I did a search beforehand, but the thousands of responses didn't filter that one to the top.. I'll check it out.

Comment: Checked out that post, and the community wiki page. I agree it's probably the best solution available, but it also seems like it would clutter up the wiki section. (Granted I guess there really is no "wiki section", there's just a bunch of posts that are rep-free labelled Wiki.) Thanks Servy